# I cannot seem to get SDL to work with sublime text

Tags: c++, linux, sublimetext3, sdl

I am making a simple game and wanted to use SDL for the graphics. I run linux Ubuntu, and use sublime text editor, g++ compiler, and I am coding in c++. I downloaded SDL and followed [these steps](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/linux/index.php).

After I followed those steps, all of the SDL error stopped appearing. However, the flag variables aren't working.

This is the code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
Risk() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_HAPTIC);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Board",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 500,500, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_GetError();
}
```

The error appearing in my compiler is:

```
tom@TBT-XPS-13-9360:~/Documents/Subjects/CS/Fun/Risk$ g++ -std=c++14 
Game.cpp -W/tmp/ccLwSxiL.o: In function `Risk::Risk()':
Game.cpp:(.text._ZN4RiskC2Ev[_ZN4RiskC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference 
to `SDL_Init'
Game.cpp:(.text._ZN4RiskC2Ev[_ZN4RiskC5Ev]+0x44): undefined reference 
to `SDL_CreateWindow'
Game.cpp:(.text._ZN4RiskC2Ev[_ZN4RiskC5Ev]+0x54): undefined reference 
to `SDL_GetError'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think the error is the SDL libraries are in the wrong place, or Sublime doesn't know where they are.

Comment: Those are linker errors, which means that the linker can't find the libraries it needs to satisfy the missing symbols. The most obvious reason for that would be that you're using the `C++ Single File` built in build system, which doesn't include any extra libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Sublime is not adding the required instruction to indicate that the executable should be linked to the SDL2 library.

You can indicate it with the parameter *-lSDL2* on the command line, or use the sdl2-config program with `sdl2-config --libs`, something like this:

`$ g++ -o executable-name source.cpp -lSDL2`

or

`$ g++ -o executable-name source.cpp $(sdl2-config --libs)`

*sdl2-config* is just an utility that outputs appropriate configuration options for compiling and linking. You can see it by running it alone:

`$ sdl2-config --libs`

it should output something like:

`-L/usr/lib -lSDL2`

You can see the same *-lSDL2* mentioned before, and also a -L/usr/lib instruction that indicates the linker to include libraries in the */usr/lib/* directory in its search path.
In general, you should use the *sdl2-config* for getting the required configuration options to pass to the compiler instead of indicating them by yourself, unless you know what you're doing, of course.

Instead of going to the command line to compile, you can use the Make build system in Sublime Text. Add a file named Makefile to your project directory with the following content:

```
# OBJS place here every file to compile as part of the project
OBJS = Game.cpp

# CC compiler to use
CC = g++

# COMPILER_FLAGS compilation options
COMPILER_FLAGS = -std=c++14 -Wall `sdl2-config --cflags`

# LINKER_FLAGS libraries to link
LINKER_FLAGS = `sdl2-config --libs`

# OBJ_NAME executable
OBJ_NAME = mygame

all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

Then go to menu *Tools* -> *Build System* and select *Make*. Now try building your project, if successful, a *mygame* executable should have been created.

Comment: The parameters you mentioned, am I including it on the c++ file, or on the Linux command line?

Comment: On the Linux command line, when you are trying to compile your file. The Makefile I posted includes them, if you select the *Make* Build system in Sublime and add a file named *Makefile* with the content I posted, you should be able to compile using the Build menu option in Sublime.

Comment: It says I am missing  a separator Error: *** missing separator. Stop.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to compile, but am having trouble with the SDL. This question is answered, Thanks